# Open pdf viewer from content uri at Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

I store the pdf file using this code:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "application/pdf"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, file.name)
        }
startActivityForResult(intent, SAVE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

and after at onActivityResult Im saving data using OutputStream. Uri to file can look like:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/4594
or
content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/documentId
```

But when im trying to start activity with this intent, pdf viewer app show error:

```
 val openFileIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contentUri)
                            .apply {
                                setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf")
                                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                            }
```

Is it possible to open pdf viewer activity from content Uri?

Comment: Which error is shown by pdf viewer?

Comment: You should set yet a flag Intent.GRAND_READ_URI ( Or whatever it is called).

Comment: @blackapps, thank you. Flag: Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the Comments have the answer: [blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792043/open-pdf-viewer-from-content-uri-at-android-q#comment111041885_62792043) and [Андрей Макаренко](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792043/open-pdf-viewer-from-content-uri-at-android-q#comment111042155_62792043)

```
val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
target.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
target.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

val intent: Intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File")

try {
     startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
     // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here
}
```

Adding the "or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION" to the flags got my PDF reader to open the file correctly with the content:// Uri structure.